# Need help in mysql join query - codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have a table in mysql with the following data

[CODE]
Table name Test

```
Assettype   Serial_No     Status            location    
Mouse        123456      In Stock           chennai
Mouse        98765       Allocated          chennai
Keyboard     23498       In Stock           bangalore
Keyboard     45646       Allocated          bangalore
Mouse        234234      Decommisioned      hyderabad
```

i am looking for a mysql query which will give the below mentioned output

```
Assettype              In Stock    Allocated    Decommisioned       Location  
Mouse                   1            1             0                chennai          
Keyboard                1            1             0                bangalore
Mouse                   0            0             1                hyderabad
```

Kindly help

Comment: And what have you tried to do for yourself

Comment: Looks like your initial database design need refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `group by` on assettype and location and find the counts like this:

```
select 
  assettype,
  sum(status = 'In Stock') In_stock,
  sum(status = 'Allocated') Allocated,
  sum(status = 'Decommisioned') Decommisioned,
  location
from test
group by assettype, location;
```

Comment: hi Guru, when i put the same query in codeigniter its giving error from controller, call to underfine function $query.

Comment: I've no knowledge of php but I can assure you that this query doesn't have any issues. You should post the problem as a new question along with the error details.